# Set column width dynamically while exporting DATA ONLY to excel in c# using crystal report (ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

I am using the below code

```
// Declare variables and get the export options.
ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
ExcelFormatOptions excelFormatOpts = new ExcelFormatOptions();
DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
exportOpts = rpt.ExportOptions;

// Set the excel format options.
excelFormatOpts.ExcelConstantColumnWidth = 100;
excelFormatOpts.ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = true;
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord;
exportOpts.FormatOptions = excelFormatOpts;

// Set the disk file options and export.
exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
diskOpts.DiskFileName = strFilename;
exportOpts.DestinationOptions = diskOpts;

rpt.Export();
```

I am getting the data's exported to excel correctly without formating.

Question: *Now I need to format. I want to set column width in the excel.*

Can I do it?

From my above code the below lines seems not to function

```
excelFormatOpts.ExcelConstantColumnWidth = 100;
excelFormatOpts.ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = true;
```

I appreciate any help in this regard as this issue is eating my time.

Answer (score 0):

i am assuning that you have excel worksheet object with a name esheet.

```
esheet.Cells.Style.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

try this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

But I am not using excel worksheet object.

I use crystal report. Please refer below code.

rpt = new REPORT_NAME();

rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(DATASET object);

This code is followed by the obove posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code.

1. With ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord you should use ExcelDataOnlyFormatOptions class, not ExcelFormatOptions. ExcelFormatOptions corresponds to ExportFormatType.Excel
2. ExcelConstantColumnWidth in C# version is in twips and 100 is very small value. You should multiply it by 20.

I managed to get working code for ExportFormatType.Excel case, but not for ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord. Other properties of ExcelDataOnlyFormatOptions work, but ExcelConstantColumnWidth still doesn't work for me.